# Form entity type options pre-checked

Tags: symfony

I have a form field which displays a bunch of checkboxes, the field is an `EntityType`. When the form renders on the front-end, a bunch of the checkboxes, not all, are already checked.

I'd like all options to be unchecked when the form renders but I can't figure out why specific ones are already checked. Below is what I currently have:

```
->add('example', EntityType::class, [
   'class' => Example::class,
   'multiple' => true,
   'required' => false,
   'by_reference' => false,
   'expanded' => true,
   'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $repository) use ($client) {
        return $repository
            ->createQueryBuilder('ex')
            ->join('ex.quote', 'e', Expr\Join::WITH, 'e.client = :client')
            ->setParameter('client', $client->getId());
    },
]);
```

I have tried adding things like:

```
'choice_attr' => [
    'checked' => false,
]
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: It seems you are passing an already persisted entity to the form. You need to remove the checked items form its 'exampe' collection before or you can use form events to clear that out.

Comment: Can you share you controller action code where you wire the form with the request and the form factory?

Comment: @mblaettermann Ah thank you! It appears the method it was calling (due to by reference), as you said had already persisted entities. Managed to solve it based on that, thanks.